# Convert HTML entities in Json back to characters

Tags: php, json, html-entities

**Problem and original data**

I have a json data which contain some HTML entities to encode some special characters (mostly from French language, like “é”, “ç”, “à”, etc.) and for html tags.
This is a sample of my json data:

```
{
    "data1": "&lt;p&gt;Le cartulaire de 1380-1381 copi&amp;eacute; au XVIIe si&amp;egrave;cle et aujourd&amp;rsquo;hui perdu&lt;strong&gt;*&lt;/strong&gt;.",
    "data2": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;*&lt;/strong&gt; Joseph CUVELIER, &lt;em&gt;Cartulaire de l&amp;rsquo;abbaye du Val-Beno&amp;icirc;t&lt;/em&gt;, Bruxelles, 1906, p. XI-XXVII.&lt;/p&gt;"
}
```

**Desired result**

```
{
    "data1": "<p>Le cartulaire de 1380-1381 copié au XVIIe siècle et aujourd’hui perdu<strong>*</strong>.",
    "data2": "<p><strong>*</strong> Joseph CUVELIER, <em>Cartulaire de l’abbaye du Val-Benoît</em>, Bruxelles, 1906, p. XI-XXVII.</p>"
}
```

So, I wish to simply decode all HTML entities back to their respective characters and tags. I try to do this with php.

**There is my current code:**

```
/* decode data */

$jsonData = '{
        "data1": "&lt;p&gt;Le cartulaire de 1380-1381 copi&amp;eacute; au XVIIe si&amp;egrave;cle et aujourd&amp;rsquo;hui perdu&lt;strong&gt;*&lt;/strong&gt;.",
        "data2": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;*&lt;/strong&gt; Joseph CUVELIER, &lt;em&gt;Cartulaire de l&amp;rsquo;abbaye du Val-Beno&amp;icirc;t&lt;/em&gt;, Bruxelles, 1906, p. XI-XXVII.&lt;/p&gt;"
    }';
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

/* change html entities and re-encode data */

$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset="UTF-8"');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

**My current result:**

```
{
    "data1": "<p>Le cartulaire de 1380-1381 copi&eacute; au XVIIe si&egrave;cle et aujourd&rsquo;hui perdu<strong>*</strong>.",
    "data2": "<p><strong>*</strong> Joseph CUVELIER, <em>Cartulaire de l&rsquo;abbaye du Val-Beno&icirc;t</em>, Bruxelles, 1906, p. XI-XXVII.</p>"
}
```

So, HTML tags were well transformed. But the HTML entities for French special characters stay here (but instead, for example `&amp;eacute;` now I have `&eacute;` ).

**Question.**
How I can convert HTML entities  back to characters?

**You can test it online here: https://www.tehplayground.com/Z4uB5KIPPo4UQ4h1**

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Finally, my data is more complex than I was imagining. In the same data some characters were preserved as “é”, “à”, “ç” etc. and some other characters was converted to HTM entities. So I can have something like this:

```
{
    "someData1":
    {
        "data1":
        [
            "ecclésiastique"
        ],
        "data2": "s&amp;eacute;culiers"
    },
    "someData2":
    [
        {
            "anotherData1": "ecclésiastique",
            "anotherData2": "&lt;p&gt;Le cartulaire de 1380-1381 copi&amp;eacute; au XVIIe si&amp;egrave;cle et aujourd&amp;rsquo;hui perdu&lt;strong&gt;*&lt;/strong&gt;.",
            "anotherData3":
            {
                "text1": "texte here",
                "text2": "texte here"
            }
        },
        {
            "anotherData1": "ecclésiastique",
            "anotherData2": "&lt;p&gt;Le cartulaire de 1380-1381 copi&amp;eacute; au XVIIe si&amp;egrave;cle et aujourd&amp;rsquo;hui perdu&lt;strong&gt;*&lt;/strong&gt;.",
            "anotherData3":
            {
                "text1": "texte here",
                "text2": "texte here"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I suppose I have to 1) Convert all data to HTML entities; 2) Convert all HTML entities back to characters…

There is my current code:

```
# Get data

$jsonData = '{
    "someData1":
    {
        "data1":
        [
            "ecclésiastique"
        ],
        "data2": "s&amp;eacute;culiers"
    },
    "someData2":
    [
        {
            "anotherData1": "ecclésiastique",
            "anotherData2": "&lt;p&gt;Le cartulaire de 1380-1381 copi&amp;eacute; au XVIIe si&amp;egrave;cle et aujourd&amp;rsquo;hui perdu&lt;strong&gt;*&lt;/strong&gt;.",
            "anotherData3":
            {
                "text1": "texte here",
                "text2": "texte here"
            }
        },
        {
            "anotherData1": "ecclésiastique",
            "anotherData2": "&lt;p&gt;Le cartulaire de 1380-1381 copi&amp;eacute; au XVIIe si&amp;egrave;cle et aujourd&amp;rsquo;hui perdu&lt;strong&gt;*&lt;/strong&gt;.",
            "anotherData3":
            {
                "text1": "texte here",
                "text2": "texte here"
            }
        }
    ]
}';

$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

# Convert character encoding

$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");

# Convert HTML entities to their corresponding characters

function html_decode(&$item){
    $item = html_entity_decode($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($data, 'html_decode');

var_dump ($data);
```

So, I succeed in reversing the encoding. These who was an HTML entities become special characters, and those who was a special character become HTML entities.

But I don't have any idea how to get only special characters.

**Online test: https://www.tehplayground.com/bVo3Jr5O7L9p4MXX**

Comment: Are you looking for: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Or perhaps this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Thank Evert and Kpie. I tried with html_entity_decode like this `$data = array_map("html_entity_decode", $data);` and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot! Sorry Kpie, I didn’t try yet `htmlspecialchars_decode`!

Comment: A little problem. It works for simple data, but when I have an array, it doesn’t work any more. `html_entity_decode` need to have a string…

Comment: The example above you said was working is already decoding each part of the array separately. Are you saying there is maybe a more complex, nested array or something? Update the question to give a specific example, and show how you tried to decode it.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question

Comment: JSON is not HTML. I would not HTML-encode any characters in it. You can certainly use unicode characters in JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the solution. I needed to

1. convert  `&amp;` to `&` to standardize encoding systems;
2. convert all applicable characters to HTML entities.

There is the final code. Many thanks to all for all your comments and suggestions.

**Full code and online test here: https://www.tehplayground.com/zythX4MUdF3ric4l**

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$item, $key) {
    if(is_string($item)) {
        $item = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $item); // 1. Replace &amp; by &
        $item = html_entity_decode($item); // 2. Convert HTML entities to their corresponding characters
    }
});
```